# OleDbDataAdapter UPDATE query comparing date type with string

Tags: c#, sql, string, date

I have an `OleDbDataAdapte`r that is doing an `UPDATE` on a database.
On the table that I am updating I have a column named `"Temp_date"` that holds dates in the `mm/dd/yyyy` format.
Is there any way I can compare the string from the table with an actual DateTime (current date)? My purpose is that if the date stored in the table is lower than the current date then to have the old value deleted.I would really appreciate your help or suggestions!

Here is what my code looks like:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter3 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter3.UpdateCommand = conexiuneBD.CreateCommand();
adapter3.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE table SET Occupied=No, Temp_date=? WHERE Temp_date<?";
adapter3.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", DBNull.Value);
adapter3.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", current_date);
```

Comment: What are the types of `Temp_date` and `current_date`?  They should both be dates (not strings) to make date comparison easy.

Comment: I know that, but my problem is that the date in the table is saved as a string.

Comment: Would something like this work: UPDATE table SET Occupied=No, Temp_date=? WHERE (Temp_date AS DATETIME)<?"  Or use CONVERT or CAST?

Comment: I am using an Acces MDB database, thus I cannot use such functions unfortunately.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Access MDB support vbscripting, let me take a look... You should include "ms-access" tag, then.

Comment: hi, @user3605321, check if this answer works for you.

Comment: @celemo Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: This is the access string-to-date conversion: UPDATE table SET Occupied=No, Temp_date=? WHERE cDate(Format("20130423014854","yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")) < ?

Answer (score 0):

What about converting the date first and just passing the constant value to compare?

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter3 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter3.UpdateCommand = conexiuneBD.CreateCommand();
string convertedDate = ConvertDateToAccessFormat(current_date);
adapter3.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE table SET Occupied=No, Temp_date=? WHERE Temp_date<" + convertedDate;
adapter3.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", DBNull.Value);
adapter3.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", current_date);
```

Or you could make it a two part process.  First, get the current value of Temp_date from the database, and only if it is less than your prospective new date would you call the update code.

Or you could use the access string-to-date conversion:

```
UPDATE table SET Occupied=No, Temp_date=? WHERE cDate(Format(Temp_date,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")) < ?
```

And BTW, if Temp_date is stored as a string, aren't you going to have to send it in as a string?  In that case you'll have to convert both values in order to compare them as dates.  Something like this?

UPDATE table SET Occupied=No, Temp_date=? WHERE cDate(Format(Temp_date,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")) < cDate(Format(?,"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))